# Is .dup really creating a shallow copy?

Tags: ruby

I am having some trouble understanding the concept of a shallow copy and the `#dup` method

I have this code

```
class MyObject
end

myObject1 = MyObject.new
myObject2 = MyObject.new
```

I know this will print false becuase I am testing for object equality, not value equality

```
p myObject1 == myObject2
```

But according to the [definition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Object.html#method-i-dup) of a shallow copy

> .dup produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.

I had expected this to print true, but it also prints false

```
p myObject1 == myObject1.dup
```

Isn't the definition wrong then? Shouldn't `myObject1.dup` an `instance variable` that points to the same object as `myObject1`, except it's clearly not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget that `==` is actually a method from [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D):

> **obj == other → true or false**
>   Equality — At the Object level, `==` returns `true` only if `obj` and other are the same object. Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning.

So if you haven't provided your own implementation of `==` (i.e. a `MyObject#==` method) then your:

```
p myObject1 == myObject1.dup
```

is pretty much the same as saying:

```
p myObject1.object_id == myObject1.dup.object_id
```

and since `myObject1.dup` is a shallow copy of `myObject1` (i.e. they're different objects), you get `false`.

When they say:

> instance variables of `obj` are copied

they're referring to the instance variables *inside* `obj`, not variables that happen to reference `obj`. Your `myObject1` isn't an instance variable in anything, it is just a variable, instance variables are referenced with a leading `@` as in `@my_instance_variable`.

If you want `==` to behave they way you expect it to then you have to provide your own `==` implementation:

```
class MyObject
  def ==(other)
    # Check that the contents of `self` and `other` are the same
    # and probably that `other.is_a?(MyObject)` first.
  end
end
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking. What I meant to say is, doesn't this definition `.dup produces a shallow copy of obj—the instance variables of obj are copied, but not the objects they reference.` imply that `p myObject1 == myObject1.dup` should print true? Basically, the language makes it sound like `.dup` duplicates the pointers, but that they still point at the same object. Get what I'm asking now?

Comment: But `myObject` is just a variable (not an instance variable) and the documentation is saying that `dup` copies the instance variables *inside* `obj`. `myObject1` and `myObject1.dup` are completely different objects and you haven't provide your own `==` so `myObject1 == myObject1.dup` is `false`. I also added a little clarification to my answer so I'll just ignore that idiot bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally got it. I was confusing an `instance variable` with a `pointer` basically